# MySQL Replication on PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I had a questions about setting up PHP application so that it reads from the proper Amazon RDS Replication.

Details:
I have setup MySQL database on AWS RDS and created replication in different zones like US-EAST, US-WEST, EU etc. Now the RDS has different public URLs for each replication. I also have servers in those zones on which I have hosted my php application.

My question is how can I setup my php application so that it reads from the replication of its own zone.

Comment: This is simple service configuration stuff.  What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking ok creating config file and based on server IP use the associated replication. I am not sure if there any other better way to do it.

Comment: Are you familiar with AWS metadata API's?

Comment: No, I am not but will look it up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu might strongly consider using the AWS metadata API.  See here for documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Using this you can call an endpoint such as

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

To get the availablity zone the instance was launched in.

Based on this you can could have a config file such as

```
{
    'rds_endpoint': {
        'us-east-1': '[RDS endpoint information]',
        'us-west-1': '[RDS endpoint information]',
        ...
    }
}
```

You application could then read its availability zone information from the API, and look up the proper RDS endpoint from the configuration map.